# WYSIWYG XML Editor (DTD or RelaxNG or XSD based grammars)

Tags: xml, xslt, wysiwyg, sgml, wysiwym

I'm need to make a WYSIWYG XML editor for a custom XML grammar.
I have explored all the OpenSource tools that **I could find** under this domain.
Includes VEX, Oxygen, Bitflux...

None of them served my purpose.

I'm also looking for javascript-based WYSIWYG HTML editors which can support and additional DOCTYPE with DTD or any grammar. I already checked out FCK and CKEditor and TinyMCE kind of editors.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3599569/112053

Comment: What exactly does "WYSIWYG XML Editor" mean? Do you mean syntax highlighting? Why did the tools you tried not serve your purpose? That is important info for people making new suggestions.

Comment: I knew this type of question was already asked. But sorry that I didn't know what was a fair next step to bring up that. Thanks for  the link. That was informative. Jaxe is what I'm looking at now. All the above where not serving my purpose because, None of them were really extendable to my XML format or didn't merely offered any good way to extend it.

Comment: Visual Studio (2008 or 20010) has a great XML editor which implements schema-based editing, prompting and intellisense. It isn't open source, but VS2008 probably can be obtain at a minimum price -- if not for free. I think that Oxygen must also have similar functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jaxe is ideal to create a GUI with a custom XML grammar (although you could say I'm biased, since I wrote most of it ;-)

See [How to create an XML language and its XML editor in 5 minutes](http://jaxe.sourceforge.net/demo_en/in_five_minutes.html) for an example (you can skip the "Definition of the XML language" part since you already have it). Or you can open an XSD file and choose the export to config menu as explained in the configuration files syntax documentation, to automatically create a config file from a schema.

However, as opposed to other XML editors, Jaxe does not try to be "WYSIWYG", it tries to be "WYSIWYM", even though it has a graphical interface. So, what you see generally does not look like the end result, it tries to convey the meaning of the XML elements, with visible tags. This results in semantically better documents, but users need to be aware of what semantic editing means, so that might or might not be what you're looking for...

Comment: Hi,Now the main problem is that I want Jaxe inside an eclipse plugin. Eclipse UI is in SWT. But Jaxe is in SWING. This is the major problem that I'm facing. Is there an SWT version of Jaxe or is there any such Library in SWT ?