# Online WYSIWYG XML editor

Tags: javascript, xml, open-source, editor, wysiwyg

Is there any open source online WYSIWYG Editor for various XML documents? I think the style could be added by XSLT, but if there is an editor, wich uses some other way to assign style to an XML file, I'm intrested.

EDIT: I've checked Xopus, Jaxe, Vex, Oxygen, Bitflux already, but none of them are matches the conditions above (not opensource, not online, etc)

Comment: What kind of style are you referring to? Plain old XML has no style. It's simply markup.

Comment: Heh, this was asked only today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675804/wysiwyg-xml-editor-dtd-or-relaxng-or-xsd-based-grammars

Comment: I'm out of close votes for today but this looks like a good duplicate to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574674/wysiwyg-editor-for-xsl-transformed-xml-outputting-back-into-xml

Comment: Sorry, I looked that in related questions, but I couldn't find that one. I will try that, thanks.

Justin: Yeah, you are right, the editor should handle xslt, i think.

Comment: @mimrock no problem. Nice gravatar by the way! Is that from Commander Keen?

Comment: @Pekka Yes, from Commander Keen 4:)

Comment: @mimrock I *knew* it :) Nice!

Comment: Hmm, I've just checked this Jaxe and it's not an online thing. XOPUS isn't good too, it's not open source(well, it's source is obfuscated) and definetly not free.

So my question is still not solved:(

Comment: Hmm... The question from today may still yield something!

Comment: @Pekka: Bitflux is abandoned long time ago, and maybe broken too(it wants mozilla 1.6 to work :D), Vex and Oxygen aren't online.

Comment: @mimrock I mean that more may still come up, the question is still young.

Comment: @Pekka: I see, sorry then, I'm newbie.

Answer (score 2):

[WebJaxe](http://media4.obspm.fr/outils/webjaxe/en/) is the online equivalent of Jaxe. It's actually more than that, since it has CMS features. As with Jaxe, you can change the look of XML elements in the editor with a config file. WebJaxe can use a PHP script and an XSLT transform to generate a website with the XML.